# Drag-Drop list transfer between components by dropping on navigation label of destination component

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm trying to figure out how to drop an element from one list onto a `<div>` and have that item change lists.

The goal is to be able to drop items from one list onto the labels in a sidebar navigation and have the item be switched to the list on that destination page.

I've attempted implementing a very simple proof of concept on stackblitz, but to no avail.

Is it possible to drop an item to a given div (even one that doesn't display a list) and have that item switch lists?

Here's the link to the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-special-drop-zone

In the stackblitz, I'm trying to be able to drop items from the TODO list onto the DONE header and have them added to the DONE list.

EDIT: Here's a GIF of what I'm trying to accomplish. Upon dropping onto 'Backlog' in the side nav, I want it to switch to the backlog list.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Add all the `cdkDrop*` attributes to the div you want to be able to drop on, just don't render the list. Make sure it shares the same `cdkDropListdata` property that the visible list does. See stackblitz links for examples.

---

I've found 2 ways to solve this problem. Both require treating the drop zone `<div>` as an independent cdkDropList.

### 1. Using `cdkDropListConnectedTo`

Documentation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cdkdroplistgroup

Stackblitz:[CdkDropListConnectedTo Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdkdroplistconnectedto)

Connect the origin list to the invisible 'drop' list (that's just a div/label), using `cdkDropListConnectedTo`.

### 2. Using `cdkDropListGroup`

[See Documentation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cdkdroplistgroup)

Stackblitz: [CdkDropListGroup Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cdkdroplistgroup)

Use the `cdkDropListGroup` directive on a `div` that contains all the lists that you want to be able to drag/drop between. They will be automatically connected as if you had used `cdkDropListConnectedTo` on each of them, with all their unique names.

---

To be able to drop on a label and have it end up in a list, follow the same process as above by having the visible list and the label share the same `cdkDropListdata` property.

In some cases this isn't possible as the label and the visible list might be in different components and getting their data from a data service or observable. In this case, you'll want to handle the `drop` event, and update the lists yourself instead of just using `transferArrayItem()`. If the components have subscribed to changes, the behavior will be the same.

Comment: I feel I have a similar problem but I couldn't understand how you managed to solve it. I have an emails list in one component and folders tree to the side of it. I want to be able to drag email into a folder and make that email go into that folder. Could you please help me understand how to achieve such behavior?